# How to ensure dispose() will be called before new widget's initState()?

Tags: flutter

I want to use a couple of functions every time the widget is created and disposed of. But after I navigate to the next page (another widget) I expect the previous widget's `dispose()` should be called first. And after that, the next widget's `initState()` is called. But it is not working like that. I navigate to the next page and that page's `initState()` is called. After that previous widget's `dispose()` is being called.

How can I ensure that the previous widget's `dispose()` called first before the next widget's `initState()`? Or how can I achieve the same behavior without `dispose()`?

Answer (score 4):

When you are navigating to from widget A to B the first will only completely `dispose()` and `deactivate()` after the transition completes. That means that in between, both A and B are being rendered, hence, the first didn't dispose yet and the second has already inited — which makes sense, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see both at the same time when transitioning.

Because of that, you should ensure that the logic from your widget B doesn't rely on disposing widget A and decouple the dependencies between them.

Maybe by providing your use case I can update my answer with a better approach for what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My app is displaying a video and I wanna keep the device awake during the video. Therefore, I use  `Wakelock.enable()` in `initState()` and it is working. After user navigates somewhere else I need to disable wakelock with `Wakelock.disable()`. In my particular case, user can skip to the next video. And because I use the same widget to display videos, everytime I navigate to the next video, in `initState()` I call `Wakelock.enable()` and it is totally okay. But I also wanna use `dispose()` just because to use `Wakelock.disable()`.

Comment: If there is anyway to ensure that I call `Wakelock.disable()` before next widget calls in its `initState()` `Wakelock.enable()`. Vice versa is not suitable because first `initState()` calls `Wakelock.enable()` and the previous widget's `dispose()` will call `Wakelock.disable()`. And this is not expected.

Comment: Yes, you can move that call to `deactivate()` instead of `dispose()` since it will be called immediately. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, `deactivate()` is still called after next widget's `initState()`

Comment: Ok, you’re correct. You’ll need another approach by adding a navigator observer to your widget’s state. From there, you can override methods that will tell you when another widget is pushed or popped.

Comment: Can you update your answer according to your newest approach?